# Unable to send message to kafka topic from neo4j stream

Tags: java, apache-kafka, neo4j, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I'm trying to send messages from neo4j stream to kafka topic.

this is my docker-compose configuration for neo4j

```
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.5.8-enterprise
    hostname: klinks
    container_name: klinks
    volumes:
      - ./plugins:/plugins
    ports:
    - "7474:7474"
    - "7687:7687"
    environment:
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_query_threshold: 0s
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_query_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_cypher_lenient__create__relationship: "true"
      NEO4J_apoc_trigger_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted: "apoc.*,algo.*"
      NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT: "yes"
      NEO4J_dbms_logs_debug_level: DEBUG
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size: 2G
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size: 1G
      NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size: 1G
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/admin  #la password è admin
      NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT: "yes"
      NEO4J_kafka_group_id: p2
      NEO4J_streams_sink_topic_cypher_friends: "
        MERGE (p1:Person { name: event.initiated }) 
        MERGE (p2:Person { name: event.accepted }) 
        CREATE (p1)-[:FRIENDS { when: event.date }]->(p2)
      "
      NEO4J_streams_sink_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_streams_procedures_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_streams_source_enabled: "true"
      NEO4J_kafka_zookeeper_connect: docker.for.win.localhost:2181
      NEO4J_kafka_bootstrap_servers: docker.for.win.localhost:9092
      NEO4J_streams_source_topic_nodes_recommendations: Person{*}
      NEO4J_streams_source_schema_polling_interval: 10000
      NEO4J_kafka_acks: 1
      NEO4J_kafka_num_partitions: 1
      NEO4J_kafka_retries: 2
      NEO4J_kafka_batch_size: 16384
      NEO4J_kafka_buffer_memory: 33554432
      NEO4J_kafka_session_timeout_ms: 15000
      NEO4J_kafka_reindex_batch_size: 1000
      NEO4J_kafka_connection_timeout_ms: 10000
      NEO4J_kafka_replication: 1
      NEO4J_kafka_linger_ms: 1
```

my final flow should be

1 [**OK**]. Send a message to  `friends` topic on `kafka` with a java producer

2 [**OK**]. Publish this `friends` stream to `neo4j` using the neo4j sink connector applying this rule

```
  MERGE (p1:Person { name: event.initiated }) 
        MERGE (p2:Person { name: event.accepted }) 
        CREATE (p1)-[:FRIENDS { when: event.date }]->(p2)
```

3 [**Not works**]. Stream back to `kafka` some data from a `neo4j` query or listen on some kind of node
In my configuration (just for testing purpose) i listen on Node of type `Person{*}`

```
...
  NEO4J_streams_source_topic_nodes_recommendations: Person{*}
...
```

Step 1 and 2 works as expected, step 3 fail, i see this logs from `neo4j`

```
klinks   | 2020-10-02 11:01:17.402+0000 DEBUG Trying to send a transaction event with txId 8 and txEventId 8 to kafka -> recommendations
klinks   | 2020-10-02 11:02:17.404+0000 DEBUG Sent record in partition null offset null data null key size null
```

i think i missing something in the configuration of the neo4j stream. Can someone help me to understand.

Comment: I try with a full docker-compose stack..including kafka services and it works as expected. So i think the in this case is in a network configuration error.

Comment: By the way, your question does not show step 2.

Comment: It was just a missing `

Comment: missing ' where????

Comment: In the question, near the point 2, but is was just a formatting error, not related to the question itself.